# how to use timepicker to make alarm clock

Tags: java, android, timepicker

Right now I am making a simple alarm clock. It has to activities. One is main and the other is "test". On the main I have created one button to set an alarm. The button is called "new" and it lead to the second activity test. In test I have a time picker and two buttons. One called "cancel" which leads back to main activity. The other is "done" which should save the time that I have picked on the time picker. I have the done button working but I don't know how to do the rest. I am very new to programming. Right now I want to know how to safe the time that I have picked on the time picker so I can access it later on to compare it with the real time. I hope to save the time when I click the "done" button. Please be as specific as possible. I am really new to this. Thank you!!!!!!!!

below are the codes I have so far

activity_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Test" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:onClick="doneButton"
        android:text="Done" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/done"
        android:layout_below="@+id/done"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:onClick="cancelButton"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Test.java

```
package com.example.alarmclock;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class Test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button cancelButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void cancelButton(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void onClick (View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.done:
            cancelButton(v);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```